# C# generated worksheet is read-only and locked

Tags: c#, excel, worksheet

I have a problem with opening and saving Excel file which my C# program generated. Every time I made some changes manually and try to save the Excel file, the popup message ask me to save a copy of this file because it is read-only. It is ok but annoying. My excel file is produced by my C# program. Here is my code snippet:

```
/**
 * Save the matched data
 * */
public void saveMatch(List<String> saveB, List<String> saveG, Excel.Worksheet bellSheet, Excel.Worksheet GSMSheet, String fileurl, String mCode, String prioName,int sNumber = 0)
{
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    Excel.Application newApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook newWB = newApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
    Excel.Worksheet newWS = newWB.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
    String colName1 = bSheet.get_Range("A1").Cells.Value;
    String colName2 = GSheet.get_Range("A1").Cells.Value;
    int i = 2;//start copy from row two of the Sheet, row one is the column name
    newWS.Cells[1, 2] = colName2;//copy the column name
    newWS.Cells[1, 1] = colName1;//copy the column name
    //Copy excatly matching data
    for (int j = 0; j < saveB.Count; j++)
    {
        newWS.Cells[i, 1] = saveB[j];
        newWS.Cells[i, 2] = saveG[j];
        //Console.WriteLine(saveG[j] + " : " + saveB[j]);
        i++;
    }
    if (sNumber==0)
    {
        if (prioName.Equals("None"))
        {
            newWB.SaveAs(fileurl + @"\MdResults_" +"None_"+ mCode + ".xlsx");
        }
        else
        {
            newWB.SaveAs(fileurl + @"\MdResults_" + prioName+"_"+mCode + ".xlsx");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (prioName.Equals("None"))
        {
            newWB.SaveAs(fileurl + @"\MdResults_" + "None_"+mCode + "_" + sNumber + ".xlsx");
        }
        else
        {
            newWB.SaveAs(fileurl + @"\MdResults_" +prioName + "_"+mCode + "_" +sNumber + ".xlsx");
        }
    }
    newWB.Close(0);
    newApp.Quit();
}
```

Program runs ok and I can open the saved Excel file successfully. I just wondering am I missing something in the C# code or I just need to modify something in Excel file itself? I want the excel file which my program generated can be modified and saved as normal without a popup message to ask me to save as a copy. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't close newApp, an Excel process will stick around in memory and keep your file locked.

Check your task list to confirm this is happening.

Try adding the following after saving your file

```
newApp.Close(0);
newApp.Quit();
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is another issue of my program. But I actually have newWB.Close(0);newApp.Quit(); in my program. But not newApp.Close(0).(I have edited my code snippet in my question.) But the problem still happens. Is that big difference by using newApp.Close(0) instead of newWB.Close(0)?

Comment: I'm not completely certain (I got my own Excel interop code working based on examples I looked for long ago). It is important to close and quit the application in order for the process to stop running. Note that I switched to EPPlus several years ago for generating and manipulating .xlsx files. It's open source and written entirely in C#. It can't do everything that Excel interop can do, but it's far easier to use (and it even works well on web servers).

Comment: Some garbage collection, might also help, after closing and quitting.

Comment: Thanks. The reason is definitely what you have explained in the answer. I missed an opened Excel.Application before my program above. I forgot to close it.